# Does every graph of clique-width 3 have a large induced subgraph of clique-width 2?

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorics

Is there a constant $\alpha>0$ such that every graph $G$ of clique-width $3$ and order $n$ has an induced subgraph of order at least $\alpha n$ and clique-width at most $2$ (in other words, the induced subgraph is a cograph)?

The best upper-bound I currently have on $\alpha$ is $3/5$, given by the cycle on five vertices $C_5$.